# Old Spanish alphabetical order

Tags: code-golf, string, sorting

Before 1994, Spanish dictionaries used alphabetical order [with a peculiarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_orthography#ref_r): digraphs `ll` and `ch` were considered as if they were single letters. `ch` immediately followed `c` , and `ll` immediately followed `l`. Adding the letter `ñ`, which follows `n` in Spanish, the order was then:

```
a, b, c, ch, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, ll, m, n, ñ, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z
```

Since 1994 `ll` and `ch` are considered as groups of two letters (`l`,`l` and `c`,`h` respectively), and thus alphabetical order is the same as in English, with the exception of the letter `ñ`.

The old order was definitely more *interesting*.

### The challenge

Input a list of zero or more words and output the list sorted according to the old Spanish alphabetical order. Sorting is between words (not between letters within a word). That is, words are atomic, and the output will contain the same words in a possibly different order.

To simplify, we will not consider letter `ñ`, or accented vowels `á`, `é`, `í`, `ó`, `ú`, or uppercase letters. Each word will be a sequence of one or more characters taken from the inclusive range from ASCII 97 (`a`) through ASCII 122 (`z`).

If there are more than two `l` letters in a row, they should be grouped left to right. That is, `lll` is `ll` and then `l` (not `l` and then `ll`).

Input format can be: words separated by spaces, by newlines, or any convenient character. Words may be surrounded  by quotation marks or not, at your choice. A list or array of words is also acceptable. Any reasonable format is valid; just state it in your answer.

In a similar way, output will be any reasonable format (not necessarily the same as the input).

Code golf, shortest wins.

### Test cases

In the following examples words are separated by spaces. First line is input, second is output:

```
llama coche luego cocina caldo callar calma
caldo calma callar cocina coche luego llama

cuchara cuchillo cubiertos cuco cueva
cubiertos cuco cuchara cuchillo cueva
```

"Words" can be single letters too:

```
b c a ch ll m l n
a b c ch l ll m n
```

or unlikely combinations (remember the rule that `l`'s are grouped left to right):

```
lll llc llz llll lllz
llc lll lllz llll llz
```

An empty input should give an empty output:

Of course, this order can be applied to other languages as well:

```
chiaro diventare cucchiaio
cucchiaio chiaro diventare

all alternative almond at ally a amber
a almond alternative all ally amber at
```

Comment: It's too late to correct the question now, because it has an answer, but actually rr was a single letter too. I believe it lost its status as a single letter later than ll and ch, so the explanation in Wikipedia is not so much wrong as partial.

Comment: "tweo"? filler+

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Thanks! corrected

Comment: @PeterTaylor Was `rr` really considered a single letter? I had never heard that http://www.rae.es/consultas/exclusion-de-ch-y-ll-del-abecedario

Comment: It was a single letter in the first Spanish dictionary I owned.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The official academy (RAE) [didn't consider `rr` a single letter](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/385); at least not since 1803. But it's true that apparently [it was considered a single letter in the Americas](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/219066/ch-ll-rr)

Comment: The Hungarian language has even more such peculiarities, and it didn't abandon them. `cs`, `dz`, `dzs`, `gy`, `ly`, `ny`, `sz`, `ty`and `zs` are all considered single letters.

Comment: @vsz hmm, with `dzs` it sounds like it would make for an even more interesting challenge because a single letter replacement wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: @vsz: Hungarian also has `ccs` for `<cs><cs>`, which makes things more interesting: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13547

Comment: Looks like Hungarian deserves a separate, much more difficult challenge :-)

Comment: @ninjalj : indeed, and technically also for `ddz`, `ddzs`, `ggy`, `lly`, `nny`, `ssz`, `tty`, and `zzs`, although a few of them are very rarely used.

Comment: I was not completely right, as the double digraphs (like `ccs` = `cs` + `cs`) have a different rule. And there are other exceptions besides digraphs. And there are a lot of accented vowels. I'll post a new challenge soon. :)

Comment: The Welsh alphabet has loads of them, and is probably interesting since they're not in (English) alphabetical order, or include all latin characters:
a, b, c, ch, d, dd, e, f, ff, g, ng, h, i, j, l, ll, m, n, o, p, ph, r, rh, s, t, th, u, w, y

Comment: @DonMuesli: rr was definitely considered a single letter by my teachers and textbooks in Argentina in the 70s.

Comment: @DonMuesli : Done: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75370/hungarian-alphabetical-order

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245860/organize-a-kiowa-library)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

**Update:** saw this got accepted and noticed a trivial 1 byte golf. Whoops.

```
:D"ll|ch|."1Q
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3AD%22ll%7Cch%7C.%221Q&input=%5B%22llama%22%2C+%22coche%22%2C+%22luego%22%2C+%22cocina%22%2C+%22caldo%22%2C+%22callar%22%2C+%22calma%22%5D&debug=0) [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3AD%22ll%7Cch%7C.%221Q&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5D%0A%5B%22llama%22%2C+%22coche%22%2C+%22luego%22%2C+%22cocina%22%2C+%22caldo%22%2C+%22callar%22%2C+%22calma%22%5D%0A%5B%22cuchara%22%2C+%22cuchillo%22%2C+%22cubiertos%22%2C+%22cuco%22%2C+%22cueva%22%5D%0A%5B%22b%22%2C+%22c%22%2C+%22a%22%2C+%22ch%22%2C+%22ll%22%2C+%22m%22%2C+%22l%22%2C+%22n%22%5D%0A%5B%22lll%22%2C+%22llc%22%2C+%22llz%22%2C+%22llll%22%2C+%22lllz%22%5D%0A%5B%22chiaro%22%2C+%22diventare%22%2C+%22cucchiaio%22%5D%0A%5B%22all%22%2C+%22alternative%22%2C+%22almond%22%2C+%22at%22%2C+%22ally%22%2C+%22a%22%2C+%22amber%22%5D&debug=0)

For each word, find all non-overlapping matches for the regex `ll|ch|.`. This splits the word into the "letters". Then, just sort the words by the splitted lists.

Comment: Great approach! (Now that I finally understand it) :-)

Comment: That code is absolutely fascinating `:D`

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `a`, 15 bytes

```
µ‛ch‛c~V‛ll‛l~V
```

Takes input as words separated by newlines, outputs a list.
[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=a&code=%C2%B5%E2%80%9Bch%E2%80%9Bc%7EV%E2%80%9Bll%E2%80%9Bl%7EV&inputs=llama%0Acoche%0Aluego%0Acocina%0Acaldo%0Acallar%0Acalma&header=&footer=)

```
µ‛ch‛c~V‛ll‛l~V    # Full program
µ                  # Sort (implicit) input by key:
       V           # Replace...
 ‛ch               # `ch`...
    ‛c~            # with `c~`
              V    # Replace...
        ‛ll        # `ll`...
           ‛l~     # with `l~`
```

Answer (score 4):

## PowerShell, <s>46</s> <s>44</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```
$args|sort @{e={$_-replace'(?=ch|ll)(.).','$1Α'}}
```

The `Α` character is the Greek letter alpha which in comes after all Latin letters in PowerShell's default sort order (at least on my machine, I'm not sure if it's different in other locales). It's counted as 2 bytes in UTF8 encoding.

Example usage, assuming this string is saved in a file named `es-sort.ps1`:

```
> es-sort.ps1 'lzego' 'luego' 'llama'

luego
lzego
llama
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 81 bytes

```
StringReplace[Sort@StringReplace[#,"ch"->"cZ","ll"->"lZ"],"cZ"->"ch","lZ"->"ll"]&
```

Same approach as TimmyD's answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```
eƬ“ch“ll”µƝÞ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/12JpHDXOSM4BETs6jhrmHth6be3je/8Ptkf//q@fkJOYmqusoqCfnJ2ekghg5panp@VCRzDyIXGJOSj6UkZNYBGVB9WUk5qWDNaYk5uapAwA)

Previous 12-byter sorted leading digraphs incorrectly, since the index took precedence over the actual character data.

```
           Þ    Sort the input by:
         µƝ     for each pair of adjacent characters as a list,
 Ƭ              apply while unique (collecting all results):
e               is it an element of
  “ch“ll”       ['ch', 'll']?
```

`eƬ2ƤÞ“ch“ll”` also works for 12 bytes, doing precisely the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Σ„ch„c~:„ll„l~:
```

I/O as a list of strings.

Very straight-forward approach, but I'm unable to find anything shorter (thus far).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OJHDfOSM0BEnRWQzMkBEXVW//9HK@XkJOYmKukoJecnZ6QC6ZzS1PR8CD8zDyyRmJOSD6FzEosgDKCOWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##HY29DcJADIX7m8IKLROkScMizuXEnfSSky4/EhFEVBmAAWjoaNghAzBEFjlsivfZ79myY891cPm6fbb3dDmcqoL29UFFlb@v/f60XrGUQkCxlPl2zAC3TDZa7wijO0ftQycRo4lKcNLSsrGj9ZxkJDUAMh3lYxpir5FaN7GpyZLseAKoJVBnIB1gRbPobzAbucEpUhMm1w2cnN7QLMQf).

**Explanation:**

```python
Σ         # Sort the (implicit) input-list of strings by:
 „ch„c~:  #  Replace all "ch" with "c~"
 „ll„l~:  #  Replace all "ll" with "l~"
          #  (and then sort it by default lexicographical order)
          # (after which the sorted list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>128</s> 116 bytes

```py
lambda p:map(''.join,sorted([{'!':'ll','?':'ch'}.get(c,c)for c in w.replace('ll','!').replace('ch','?')]for w in p))
```

I still feel like there's definitely room for improvement here.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 95 bytes

```
s=>s.map(a=>a.replace(/ll|ch/g,m=>m[0]+'~')).sort().map(a=>a.replace(/.~/g,m=>m>'d'?'ll':'ch'))
```

Comment: [77](https://tio.run/##NYtBCsMgEEWv4k6HpqbLbsxFQiCD1cQyZkRtIFB6ddssuvnv8eA/ccdic0j1ut9b86aYoeiISaEZlB8Pgzq7RGid6onedu2XLpohjrfpIj8SJoPdAaAL56rg//QjTtAsb4XJaeJFeSWJMKKwbFcn6OUWPj1sv4T04HMJ84mIUpdEoc5iBmhf)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 40 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with the list of words on STDIN:

```
perl -p spanisort.pl <<< "llama coche luego cocina caldo callar calma"
```

`spanisort.pl`

```
s/ll|ch|./\u$&/g;$_="\L@{[sort split]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.sort_by{_1.gsub(/ll|ch/){$&[0]+?|}}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3tXTtEqsT9Yrzi0rikyqr4w310otLkzT0c3JqkjP0NatV1KINYrXta2pra6E6LApKS4oV3KJVy6NzchJzExWS85MzUhVySlPT80HszDygUGJOSj6IzEksAlG5ibGxXBD9CxZAaAA)